# Cisco 1921 Router LAN network can't access any WAN routes

Tags: cisco, routing

Cisco clueless here.
I have a 1921 router that connects to multiple external networks using subinterfaces on `G0/0` and has a LAN network on `G0/1`:

```
Interface                  IP-Address      OK? Method Status                
Protocol
Embedded-Service-Engine0/0 unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/0         unassigned      YES NVRAM  up                    up      
GigabitEthernet0/0.1       10.10.0.1       YES NVRAM  up                    up      
GigabitEthernet0/0.2       10.20.0.2       YES NVRAM  up                    up      
GigabitEthernet0/0.3       172.60.74.102   YES NVRAM  up                    up      
GigabitEthernet0/1         192.168.2.252   YES NVRAM  up                    up      
NVI0                       10.10.0.1       YES unset  up                    up
```

I am trying to allow the LAN network `192.168.2.0/24` network reach any routes that are on each sub-interface.

Ive tried running `ip default-network` and `ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.2.0` but they don't help.

Each LAN IP address can reach all the external subnetwork IP addresses, but cannot reach any of the networks that those subinterfaces can reach.

Please what am I doing wrong?

My router configuration:

```
    ip dhcp excluded-address 10.10.10.1
!         
!         
!         
ip domain name usiswe.com
ip cef    
no ipv6 cef
!         
multilink bundle-name authenticated
!         
cts logging verbose
!         
crypto pki trustpoint TP-self-signed-1652834681
 enrollment selfsigned
 subject-name cn=IOS-Self-Signed-Certificate-1652834681
 revocation-check none
 rsakeypair TP-self-signed-1652834681
ip ssh rsa keypair-name mem.usiswe.com
ip ssh version 2
!         
!         
!         
!         
!         
!         
!         
!         
!         
!         
interface Embedded-Service-Engine0/0
 no ip address
 shutdown 
!         
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 description $ETH-LAN$$ETH-SW-LAUNCH$$INTF-INFO-GE 0/0$
 no ip address
 ip nat outside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!         
interface GigabitEthernet0/0.1
 encapsulation dot1Q 10
 ip address 10.10.0.1 255.255.255.0
!         
interface GigabitEthernet0/0.2
 encapsulation dot1Q 20
  ip address 10.20.0.2 255.255.255.0
!         
interface GigabitEthernet0/0.3
 encapsulation dot1Q 802
 ip address 172.60.74.102 255.255.255.252
!         
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 description QriosLAN
 ip address 192.168.2.252 255.255.255.0
 ip flow ingress
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 no mop enabled
!         
ip forward-protocol nd
!         
ip http server
ip http access-class 23
ip http authentication local
ip http secure-server
ip http timeout-policy idle 60 life 86400 requests 10000
!         
ip nat inside source list 10 interface GigabitEthernet0/1 overload
ip route 172.18.254.90 255.255.255.255 172.60.74.101
ip route 172.26.4.21 255.255.255.255 172.60.74.101
ip route 172.26.90.5 255.255.255.255 172.60.74.101
ip route 172.26.90.6 255.255.255.255 172.60.74.101
ip route 172.26.96.62 255.255.255.255 172.60.74.101
ip route 172.26.96.64 255.255.255.255 172.60.74.101
ip route 172.26.96.74 255.255.255.255 172.60.74.101
ip route 172.26.98.155 255.255.255.255 172.60.74.101
ip route 172.26.98.157 255.255.255.255 172.60.74.101
ip route 172.26.98.167 255.255.255.255 172.60.74.101
ip route 172.26.176.229 255.255.255.255 172.60.74.101
!         
!         
!         
access-list 10 permit 192.168.2.0 0.0.0.255
!         
control-plane
!
```

Comment: Did you Configure NAT policy on that router?

Comment: Please post the router configuration.  There could be several things wrong, so we'd just end up guessing.

Comment: Sorry posted the router confing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have NAT correctly configured. You have the outside NAT applied to an interface (`GigabitEthernet0/0`) which has no assigned network, and on which no traffic will be routed.

I think you are trying to set all the subinterfaces as outside NAT interfaces, but I don't see much of a reason to NAT on all the subinterfaces, which you must do individually. The `GigabitEthernet0/0.3` interface is the only one with a public IPv4 address, so it makes sense to have it as an outside NAT interface, but I don't see a reason to have the other subinterfaces using NAT unless they are inside interfaces.

The router will route between all the interfaces, as long as you have `ip routing` configured.

If you do want all the subinterfaces to be outside NAT interfaces, then you need to do something like this:

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 no ip nat outside
!         
interface GigabitEthernet0/0.1
 ip nat outside
!         
interface GigabitEthernet0/0.2
 ip nat outside
!         
interface GigabitEthernet0/0.3
 ip nat outside
!         
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 ip address 192.168.2.252 255.255.255.0
 ip nat inside
!         
ip nat inside source list 10 interface GigabitEthernet0/1.1 overload
ip nat inside source list 10 interface GigabitEthernet0/1.2 overload
ip nat inside source list 10 interface GigabitEthernet0/1.3 overload
!
access-list 10 permit 192.168.2.0 0.0.0.255
!
```

One problem with NAT is that all the conversations must be initiated from the inside. For example, you will not be able to ping from an outside network to your inside network.

Also, for the network to be able to get to all the networks on the other side of those interfaces, the router must be told about how to reach those networks. Routers learn about routes in three ways:

- Directly connected networks
- Statically configured routes
- Dynamic routing protocols

You can really only use a single default route (`0.0.0.0/0`) because it is the route used when there are not other routes to the destination. Normally, you use a default route toward the public Internet because the Internet routing table is so large that many routers simply cannot handle all the routes.

Static routes don't scale.

The ideal way is to run a routing protocol between your router and the neighboring routers.

Comment: Hi I tried to add the `ip nat inside source list 10` rules but each time I add a fresh one, the router complains of `%Dynamic mapping in use, cannot change`

Comment: You will need to disable NAT and clear the NAT table. Add what you want to add, then reenable NAT.

Comment: Curious why `ip routing` didnt work. Was there something in the config stopping it from working?

Comment: Apparently, it was working, based on what you wrote, "_Each LAN IP can reach all the external subnetwork IPs_". What doesn't work is routing to the networks about which the router knows nothing, "_cannot reach any of the networks that those subinterfaces can reach._" As I wrote, you somehow need to let the router know how to reach those networks.

Comment: Ok, but without doing the `ip nat` rules, is it possible to let the IPs on the 192.168.2.0 subnet connect to the external networks available, through the router?

Comment: That's what routing protocols are for. You could use a default route for one interface, but when you do something like it appears that you are doing, you want to use a routing protocol so that every router knows about all the routes. You could do it by defining static routes on all the routers, but that doesn't scale. Remember that the devices on the other, non-connected networks need to have a route back to your network, too. You **only use NAT if you must**, for example, when you are connecting a private network to the public Internet. NAT is a kludge, and it should be avoided, if possible.

Comment: @Sina, NAT **_is not_** a substitute for proper routing, despite people trying to use it that way. I have no idea what other routers are on the other ends of the private subinterfaces, but just about any router can run RIP. Something like OSPF would be better (fast with a simple configuration), but the network topology would matter to see how it should be correctly configured.

Comment: I dont have access to the routers on the next hop (they are an ISP trying to provide access through to some IPs). I'd really like to avoid using the static routes if possible. Is there any way I can do this without NATing?

Comment: I explained the three ways that your router can learn routes. I just don't have enough information to go beyond that. I also provided you with a correct NAT configuration, so you can do that if you want.

Comment: Beginning to think there is something else wrong. Doing a source ping and traceroute from the router LAN interface fails utterly

Comment: That is because your router has no idea where to send traffic to the other networks. I have explained this to you several times. You can configure one working static default route, where packets without a know route will be sent, but somehow, you would need to tell the router how to get to any other routes you want to reach on the other interfaces, otherwise your packets for those networks will exit the router on the interface for the default route. This is Routing 101. If you cannot run a routing protocol, then you will need to define static routes to the non-directly connected networks.

Comment: @Sina, you should not need NAT for traffic going out interfaces with private addressing from your private addressing. If the ISP is giving you private addressing on those interfaces, the ISP itself will need to perform the NAT to get the traffic to any public Internet destinations, but you will need to inform your router about each non-directly connected network on each interface (not the networks defined by the addressing on the interfaces, but the networks on the other side of those networks).

Comment: If my answer helped you, you should accept it so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.

Comment: I ended up doing `ip nat inside source list 1 interface GigabitEthernet0/0.3 overload` and `access-list 1 permit 192.168.2.0 0.0.0.255` with the static routes and I can reach from the LAN now.

Comment: You probably want to have a static default route for the public network on `GigabitEthernet0/0.3` if that is the actual Internet link. You really can't set static routes for every network on the Internet, and the more specific routes you have defined for the other interfaces will take precedence over the default route (more specific routes, those with longer masks, are always preferred over less specific routes, and the default route has a zero length, so any other routers are preferred over it). The default route will only be used if there is no route in your router.

Comment: Yes youre right. Its looking like this isnt going to be an internet router after all, and its role is to connect to certain networks for certain IP addresses. Those static routes are necessary, connecting to those IPs in the routes,  wouldnt work, except from the directly connected interface, when I removed them. Oh and I  had to add `ip nat inside` on the g0/1 LAN interface and `ip nat outside` on the g0/0.3 interface too.